# Does jQuery interval refresh reload the div separately for each user who are open in that page?

Tags: jquery

I have a div in the page where I need to call an API every 30 seconds and display the results within the same div of the page.

Here the div for API calls

```
<div id="_inPlay_dIv"> 
$url='https://example.com/v1/result?token=xxxxxx';
</div>
```

Now, my question is -- if I use jQuery div refresh at an interval of 30 seconds, will the API calls be made separately for every online users who are open in the page? I mean if there are like 100 online users who is viewing the same page simultaneously and each user refresh interval is separately done, then it will be disaster with thousands of API calls which my site will obviously wouldn't able to handle, also the cost of premium API will go up as calls increases.

Here is my jQuery snippet:

```
   jQuery(body).ready(function(){
       jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
        setInterval(function () {
          jQuery('#_inPlay_dIv').load(' #_inPlay_dIv');
         }, 30000);
       });
```

Hope someone can shed a light on this.

Comment: Each user executes it's own copy of code, so API calls to server is `UserCount X interval`. But you can use some back-end caching to produce only one call per interval, no matter how much users calls it

Comment: Also use `$(document).ready(function()...` not `body`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Appreciate it buddy. So I will need to figure out this - "Use Websockets or server sent events instead"..

Comment: @Matt glad to help. I added a more complete answer for you below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly `setInterval()` is a JS construct. It has nothing to do with jQuery.

With regard to your question, yes the call will be made every 30 seconds multiplied by the number of concurrent users on your website. As such this solution will scale incredibly badly, and is why AJAX polling should be avoided.

If you need to keep the server data and client UI in close sync use Websockets or server sent events instead.

If you're concerned about rate limiting on a third party API create a background process to poll that API *once* at the required interval and store the retrieved data in your own datastore. Then you can have your server publish data from that source.

Comment: Yes, i already tried to first store API data in database and then retrieve from there, and it does work. But I was looking for something that I don't need to necessarily call APIs when there are no users browsing the page. Appreciate your inputs

Comment: It depends on the rate the API enforces and how much it costs. In general terms it much better to have a known interval between requests so you know that you will always make exactly 2,880 requests per day instead of having to worry about starting/stopping a process when users connect to the site etc. which is always very unreliable.

Comment: Yes that sounds better. I will have more informed decision now. Cheers!